# How to run multiple queries from append variable?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Pipeline setup:
Lookup (JSON from link that generates ID for each user) > Foreach with Append Variable inside it ( [https://microsoft.com/createdby=@{item().user.value}](https://microsoft.com/createdby=@%7Bitem().user.value%7D))

Now I've many rows of Append Variable with link+ID as value.
For example: https://microsoft.com/createdby=rfegr23rfgfde3

Every row has its unique value and they all lead to a JSON file for that user.
I want to run them all (multiple links) and import to SQLDB (Copy data activity or something like that)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and what you are looking for. Like sample code or step by step guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **http** connector in copy activity to copy the data from that link to SQL database.

In your approach, you use lookup activity which lists the user ids and concat each user id with the string `https://microsoft.com/createdby=` before to it using for-each activity. You store this list of URLs in an array variable using Append Variable activity.
Since variable cannot be passed dynamically as Base URL in HTTP connector, instead of using append variable activity which stores URL in array variable, follow the below approach.

- Inside for-each activity, Use the **Copy activity**
- In Source, Create a source dataset.

  1. Click **+New**
  2. Search for HTTP and click **HTTP**
  3. Click **Continue**
     [image]
  4. Select JSON format. Click Continue.
     [image]
  5. Create a new linked service and give the Base URL as `https://microsoft.com/api`
  6. If URL is private and has credentials, give the appropriate authentication type and values. Otherwise choose Anonymous.
  7. Click create and click OK.
     [image]
- Once Source dataset is created, Click on the **edit** icon.
- Create a dataset parameter for Relative URL named `relativeURL` and pass the value `@concat('thread_createdby=',item().user.value)` for that parameter.
  [image: gif108]
- Similarly, create sink dataset for SQL database.
- I used **Auto create table** option in the sink dataset and table name as `@{item().user.value}`. So that table will be created with name of user id itself.

[image: gif108]